# Limit iPad data when tethered to iPhone (iOS equivalent of "Trip Mode" or "Little Snitch")

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, tethering, cellular-data

I am using an old iPhone to create a Wi-Fi hotspot when I need to work at my cabin.

I found "Trip Mode" for limiting data usage from my MacBook; however, my iPad seems to be a little data-hog.

**Is there any way to limit the apps** (directly on my iPad) **that can use data while tethered to the iPhone?**

i.e. **Is there an iOS equivalent of Trip Mode that I could install on the iPad?**

This seems like something that many folks would need, but I can only find really old threads discussing it when I Google it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Web search revealed this app which claims to monitor data usage on your iOS device.

- [My Data Manager VPN Security](https://itunes.apple.com/app/my-data-manager-vpn-security/id477865384)

Some of the features as listed in the app description are:

- Monitor your data usage on mobile, WiFi, and roaming
- Find out which apps are eating up your mobile data
- Get alerts before you reach your data limit to avoid overage fees

The app is available free of cost from the App Store.

**Note**: No affiliation whatsoever with the developer of the app. Based on the app description and ratings, it appears like a useful app.

Comment: Am just in the city today & have downloaded it to give it a try. Much appreciated. Will report back after giving it a shot. Frustrated that I couldn't find it in my searches: I spent a good hour or so looking up different options, and couldn't turn anything up for iOS. Thanks for your help!